# How can I change the default width of a Twitter Bootstrap modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-2

I tried the following:

```
   <div class="modal hide fade modal-admin" id="testModal" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <a data-dismiss="modal" class="close">×</a>
          <h3 id='dialog-heading'></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="dialog-data"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" >Close</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveChanges">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this Javascript:

```
    $('.modal-admin').css('width', '750px');
    $('.modal-admin').css('margin', '100px auto 100px auto');
    $('.modal-admin').modal('show')
```

The result is not what I expected. The modal top left is positioned in the center of the screen.

Can anyone help me. Has anyone else tried this. I assume it's not an unusual thing to want to do.

Comment: Bootstrap plugin don't see to have that many options. try to locate the class in the bootstrap CSS file and see if it's set via CSS, then you should be able to overwrite or at least will have a better clue about which element it is.

Comment: Look at the answer from Nick N for a very nice responsive answer! http://stackoverflow.com/a/16090509/539484

Answer (score 373, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

In `bootstrap 3` you need to change the modal-dialog.
So in this case you can add the class `modal-admin` in the place where `modal-dialog` stands.

**Original Answer (Bootstrap < 3)**

Is there a certain reason you're trying to change it with JS/jQuery?

You can easily do it with just CSS, which means you don't have to do your styling in the document.
In your own custom CSS file, you add:

```
body .modal {
    /* new custom width */
    width: 560px;
    /* must be half of the width, minus scrollbar on the left (30px) */
    margin-left: -280px;
}
```

In your case:

```
body .modal-admin {
    /* new custom width */
    width: 750px;
    /* must be half of the width, minus scrollbar on the left (30px) */
    margin-left: -375px;
}
```

The reason I put body before the selector is so that it takes a higher priority than the default. This way you can add it to an custom CSS file, and without worries update Bootstrap.

Comment: When I increased the width to 1000px, I found I needed to set the modal's style attribute "left" to 33%.

Comment: You sure you corrected the margin? It should go 50% in, and then minus the corrected margin ;-)

Comment: I think you need to leave the top-margin alone at 250px; you've changed yours to -345px above and that throws it off the top on a small screen. You only need to subtract half the additional width (above 560px default) that you added from the left margin.

Comment: @JDSmith is totally correct. I changed it to reflect only `margin-left` which they also use in bootstrap now ;-)

Comment: sucks that this isn't response. nice solution otherwise. Let's just wait for Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I use the following:
left: 5%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 90%;

Comment: Scroll below for a better (responsive) answer thanks to @NickN!

Comment: @FloatingRock you can make it responsive, look at my answer

Comment: Bootstrap 3 makes this easier. `.modal .modal-dialog { width: 800px; }` The left position is automatically calculated.

Comment: in Bootstrap 3, width should be responsive and in percent, otherwise some elements like select2 get misaligned

Comment: I would really follow this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23361606/2096928) because it uses actual Bootstrap 3 classes instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: just add the custom width to .modal-dialog element, it all.

    .modal-dialog { width: 700px }

Comment: Actually, this does not work for me. 
The solution gave in comment by @ZimSystem did the trick.

Answer (score 271):

If you want to make it responsive with just CSS, use this:

```
.modal.large {
    width: 80%; /* respsonsive width */
    margin-left:-40%; /* width/2) */ 
}
```

*Note 1: I used a `.large` class, you could also do this on the normal `.modal`*

*Note 2: In Bootstrap 3 the negative margin-left may not be needed anymore* **(not confirmed personally)**

```
/*Bootstrap 3*/
.modal.large {
     width: 80%;
}
```

*Note 3: In Bootstrap 3 and 4, there is a  `modal-lg` class. So this may be sufficient, but if you want to make it responsive, you still need the fix I provided for Bootstrap 3.*

In some application `fixed` modals are used, in that case you could try `width:80%; left:10%;` (formula: left = 100 - width / 2)

Comment: This seems to cause the modal to be half off the screen on very narrow screens.

Comment: Cofiem, use a media query to fix this

Comment: @NickN. my media query didn't fix it.  Can you add an example?  Disregard, I got it.  I had max-width instead of min-width.  `@media (min-width: 400px) {
    body .modal-lrg{
   width: 80%; /* respsonsive width */
   margin-left:-40%; /* width/2) */
  }
 }`

Comment: I find just using a % doesn't give enough control as would using the columns already built into bootstrap.

Comment: @Alex I think it gives you more control, how would you do it with the existing columns?

Comment: @NickN I have put an example in my answer below, using the percentage gives more control than just the standard modal, but using the built in responsive tools in Bootstrap gives even better control.

Comment: @mlunoe it did actually, please check which version of bootstrap and which version of IE, and maybe I can help you

Comment: Using `calc` could fix the responsive issue on narrow screens

Answer (score 108):

If you're using Bootstrap 3, you need to change the modal-dialog div and not the modal div like it is shown in the accepted answer. Also, to keep the responsive nature of Bootstrap 3, it's important to write the override CSS using a media query so the modal will be full width on smaller devices.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devincollier/tgkzK/2/) to experiment with different widths.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog custom-class">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-header-text">Text</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                This is some text.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                This is some text.
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .custom-class {
        width: 70%; /* either % (e.g. 60%) or px (400px) */
    }
}
```

Comment: correct one for bootstrap3. works without adapting margin! thx

Comment: I removed the id attribute in the answer because it's not necessary.

Comment: it works, but it is not responsive as mlunoe or Dave answers.

Comment: This is for me the real answer, it deserves more upvote

Answer (score 80):

If you want something that does not break the relative design try this:

```
body .modal {
  width: 90%; /* desired relative width */
  left: 5%; /* (100%-width)/2 */
  /* place center */
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto; 
}
```

As, @Marco Johannesen says, the "body" before the selector is so that it takes a higher priority than the default.

Comment: i recommend just using `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` instead of `auto` all the way around

Comment: in some cases one might need `top: 30%`, the percentage depending on the content inside.

Comment: This works well for me when I omit the .modal.fade.in rule, which moves the modal all the way to the bottom in Bootstrap V2.2.2.

Comment: This worked with the ANGULAR-UI modal example... Just drop the code in a css file and load in the page... 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal... Running example at http://plnkr.co/edit/GYmc9s?p=preview

Comment: great this solution works well on 2.3.2 bootstrap and MAIN in internet explorer 8,9,10!!!! solution with margin-left:-40% is incorrect in internet explorer!!!

Answer (score 41):

In Bootstrap 3+ the most appropriate way to change the size of a modal dialog is to use the size property. Below is an example, notice the `modal-sm` along the `modal-dialog` class, indicating a small modal. It can contain the values `sm` for small, `md` for medium and `lg` for large.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ww_vergeten" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_title" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm"> <!-- property to determine size -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal_title">Some modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- modal content -->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="some_button" data-loading-text="Loading...">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added it to my answer :)

Comment: Shouldn't this be the top answer? I suppose the top answer could help you customise it but most use cases should be satisfied by Bootstrap's inbuilt classes.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3.x and i don't seem to have `modal-md` class.

Answer (score 34):

For `Bootstrap 3` here's how to do it.

Add a `modal-wide` style to your HTML markup (as adapted from [the example in the Bootstrap 3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals))

```
<div class="modal fade modal-wide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and add the following CSS

```
.modal-wide .modal-dialog {
  width: 80%; /* or whatever you wish */
}
```

There is no need to override `margin-left` in `Bootstrap 3` to get this to be centered now.

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, there's no technical reason to add the `modal-wide` class, meaning that is not a Bootstrap "internal" class. You can simply do `#myModal .modal-dialog { width: 80%; }`

Comment: Yep. But doing it as a style makes it more re-usable.

Comment: Yep I understand. It's just many times it's hard to the difference between a bootstrap class and a custom class, so I wanted to make a note of it.

Answer (score 19):

In **Bootstrap 3** all you need is this

```
<style>
    .modal .modal-dialog { width: 80%; }
</style>
```

Most of the above answers did not worked for me !!!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  #myModal1 .modal-dialog {
    width: 80%;
  }
  #myModal2 .modal-dialog {
    width: 50%;
  }
</style>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
  80%
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
  50%
</button>
<center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          custom width : 80%
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          custom width : 50%
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</center>
```

Comment: Do you know how to change modal height? Thanks for your answer, it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 17):

Solution was taken from [this](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/675#issuecomment-3664958) page

```
$('#feedback-modal').modal({
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true
}).css({
    width: 'auto',
    'margin-left': function () {
        return -($(this).width() / 2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

In v3 of Bootstrap there is a simple method to make a modal larger. Just add the class **modal-lg** next to modal-dialog.

```
<!-- My Modal Popup -->
<div id="MyWidePopup" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"> <---------------------RIGHT HERE!!
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
```

Comment: Why the down vote?! It absolutely, and cleanly, gave me a nice wide dialog box! And only uses "proper" bootstrap classes!

Comment: Try tripping back some of your HTML elements - use the simplest structure you can in order to test it.

Answer (score 13):

Bootstrap 3: In order to maintain responsive features for small and extra small devices I did the following:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.modal-dialog-wide
{ width: 750px;/* your width */ }
}
```

Comment: it's right. this works for me. don't forget to change the width property to XX% for responsive layout. Btw, the version in my case is 3.0.3

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did, in my custom.css I added these lines and that was all.

```
.modal-lg {
    width: 600px!important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Obviously, you can change the size of the width.

Answer (score 7):

If Bootstrap>3, Just add style to your modal.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width:80%;">
  <div class="modal-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I've found this solution that works better for me. You can use this:

```
$('.modal').css({
  'width': function () { 
    return ($(document).width() * .9) + 'px';  
  },
  'margin-left': function () { 
    return -($(this).width() / 2); 
  }
});
```

or this depending your requirements:

```
$('.modal').css({
  width: 'auto',
  'margin-left': function () {
     return -($(this).width() / 2);
  }
});
```

See the post where I found that:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/675

Answer (score 5):

FYI Bootstrap 3 handles the left property automatically. So simply adding this CSS will change the width and keep it centered:

```
.modal .modal-dialog { width: 800px; }
```

Comment: Worked for B3! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Preserve the responsive design, set the width to what you desire.

```
.modal-content {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 360px;
}
```

Keep it simple.

Answer (score 4):

Altering the class `model-dialog` you can achieve expected result. These small tricks work for me. Hope it will help you to solve this issue.

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used a combination of CSS and jQuery, along with hints on this page, to create a fluid width and height using Bootstrap 3.

First, some CSS to handle the width and optional scrollbar for the content area

```
.modal.modal-wide .modal-dialog {
  width: 90%;
}
.modal-wide .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And then some jQuery to adjust the height of the content area if needed

```
$(".modal-wide").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
  var height = $(window).height() - 200;
  $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
});
```

Full write-up and code at
http://scottpdawson.com/development/creating-a-variable-width-modal-dialog-using-bootstrap-3/

Answer (score 3):

With Bootstrap 3, all that is required is a percentage value given to the modal-dialog via CSS

## CSS

```
#alertModal .modal-dialog{
     width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: yeap, the occam's razor goes to this one. tested on 3.0 works great

Answer (score 3):

In **Bootstrap 3** with CSS you can simply use:

```
body .modal-dialog {
    /* percentage of page width */
    width: 40%;
}
```

This ensures you don't break the design of the page, because we're using `.modal-dialog` instead of `.modal` which will be applied even to the shading.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following (see live jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/hEThw/1/)

```
<a class="btn" onclick = "$('#myModal').modal('show');$('#myModal').css('width', '100px').css('margin-left','auto').css('margin-right','auto');" ref="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" style = "display:none">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using percentages to make the modal responsive, I find there can be more control taken from using the columns and other responsive elements already built into bootstrap.

---

**To make the modal responsive/the size of any amount of columns:** 

1) Add an extra div around the modal-dialog div with a class of .container -

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    </div>
</div>
```

2) Add a little CSS to make the modal full width -

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 100% }
```

3) Alternatively add in an extra class if you have other modals -

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-responsive">
    </div>
</div>

.modal-responsive.modal-dialog {
    width: 100% }
```

4) Add in a row/columns if you want various sized modals -

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-responsive">
       ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following on your css file

```
.popover{
         width:auto !important; 
         max-width:445px !important; 
         min-width:200px !important;
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Below Script:

```
.modal {
  --widthOfModal: 98%;
  width: var(--widthOfModal) !important;
  margin-left: calc(calc(var(--widthOfModal) / 2) * (-1)) !important;
  height: 92%;

  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Demo**:

[image: Demo on gif]

Answer (score 2):

I solved it for Bootstrap 4.1

Mix of previously posted solutions

```css
.modal-lg {
  max-width: 90% !important; /* desired relative width */
  margin-left:auto !important;
  margin-right:auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Achieved expected result using,

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 41% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 3.x.x**

```
   <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="employeeBasicDetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm employeeModal" role="document">

        <form>

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body row">
                Modal Body...
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer"> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Notice I added .employeeModal class in second div. Then style that class.

```
.employeeModal{
        width: 700px;
    }
```

[image: screenshot of code snippet]

Answer (score 0):

I used this way, and it's work perfect for me

```
$("#my-modal")
.modal("toggle")
.css({'width': '80%', 'margin-left':'auto', 'margin-right':'auto', 'left':'10%'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Less-based solution (no js) for Bootstrap 2:

```
.modal-width(@modalWidth) {
    width: @modalWidth;
    margin-left: -@modalWidth/2;

    @media (max-width: @modalWidth) {
        position: fixed;
        top:   20px;
        left:  20px;
        right: 20px;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
        &.fade  { top: -100px; }
        &.fade.in { top: 20px; }
    }
}
```

Then wherever you want to specify a modal width:

```
#myModal {
    .modal-width(700px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used SCSS, and the fully responsive modal:

```
.modal-dialog.large {
    @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) { width:500px; }
    @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) { width:700px; }
    @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) { width:850px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use any prefix or postfix name for modal. but you need to make sure that's should use everywhere with same prefix/postfix name.    

body .modal-nk {
        /* new custom width */
        width: 560px;
        /* must be half of the width, minus scrollbar on the left (30px) */
        margin-left: -280px;
    }
```

or

```
body .nk-modal {
            /* new custom width */
            width: 560px;
            /* must be half of the width, minus scrollbar on the left (30px) */
            margin-left: -280px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the code for set the modal pop-up width and left position from the screen through javascript.**

$('#openModalPopupId').css({ "width": "80%", "left": "30%"});

Answer (score 0):

```
.Size(ModalSize.Large)

sample:
 using (var modal = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Modal().Id("modalProject_" + modelItem.id).Closeable().Size(ModalSize.Large)))
                {
}
```

Comment: Can you edit an explanation of this code into the question?