# Customizing existing twitter bootstrap modal styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm pretty new to CSS.  I know there is some inheritance, but besides font, I'm not always sure where it applies.  So what I'm trying to do, is modify the twitter bootstrap modal class.  There is a backbone view that is being shown currently with these classes:

```
modal hide fade
```

What I want to do is extend the width and height of the modal view but keep all of the other modal CSS properties in tact.  Is there a way to do this?  In my own local.less file for my project, I first tried doing what I googled which was [How can I change the default width of a Twitter Bootstrap modal box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169432/how-can-i-change-the-default-width-of-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-box)

But my view wasn't modal anymore.  It wasn't centered and didn't have a darkened backdrop.  So I then thought I could just copy the .modal class from twitter bootstrap into my local.less file, and then change the width/height.  So I tried that with this:

```
.modal-width-half (@modalWidth: 50%) {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;
  overflow: auto;
  width: @modalWidth;
  margin: -250px 0 0 -@modalWidth / 2;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999999;
  /* IE6-7 */

  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

And again, the style isn't modal.  Is there something I'm missing or doing incorrectly?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you compile the .less file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this and can share the line you're missing.

In my commit to change the width of the modal I had to change the `width` property and also the [`margin-left` property](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-dashboard/blob/visuals/static/less/modals.less#L32). By changing both of these you will keep the form centered.

```
.modal {
  width: @modalWidth;
  margin-left: -@modalWidth / 2;
}
```

of course this will apply to *all* modals on your site, if you want to apply it to just one modal then you can customise the class name e.g.

```
.my-modal { 
  width: @modalWidth; 
  margin-left: -@modalWidth / 2; 
}
```

You can then refer to this in your html like:

```
<div class="modal fade open my-modal">...</div>
```

Just make sure the definition for `.my-modal` comes *after* `.modal` in your less/css file or the definition will be overridden by the bootstrap style.

Comment: for some reason that doesn't work for me.  I see the my-modal class in the div in firebug.  But when I look at the actual styles applied to that div, I don't see my-modal as one of the styles.  Do you know why that would be?  Thanks.

Comment: if you like, post a jsfiddle with your css and html, i'm sure i could figure this out in 10 seconds with the actual source code.

Comment: Ah i ended up getting it from your suggestion.  I forgot what it was, but it was something in my less file that I didn't have correct preventing it from working.  Thanks!