# Bootstrap 3 modal width of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is there any way to use Bootstrap to create a modal that expands to the width of the viewport? I've seen lots of suggestions (most of which involve changing 
`.modal-dialog { width:auto}` to `.modal-dialog { width:600px }` or some other value, but I'm not seeing any results with this.

I have a modal-body and modal-header inside of a modal-content inside of a modal-dialogue inside of a modal fade.

`<div class="modal fade" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"> Header Text </div>
            <div class="modal-body"> body text </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Am I not updating the right modal class? Or is there some other secret to increasing the width of the viewport?

Comment: here the suggestion is about the modal class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169432/how-can-i-change-the-default-width-of-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-box. Changing it to width:100% should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue here was updating .modal.fade .modal-dialogue, rather than just .modal-dialogue. While other answers allowed for a workaround, this was the source of my particular problem.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation for comment, sorry for that. I've just tested this and works fine with me just by changing `.modal-dialog { width:600px; }` in my main .css file. Did you close the closing brecket for the css rule as I can see you didn't here, first. Second, can you look with Inspect element or Firebug does your rule is applied to the class or div? Is it overwritten?

Comment: By "main .css file", do you mean your bootstrap.css?

Comment: I use different css file to include my own rules or rewrite existing ones from bootstrap, so no. You can also try adding `style="width: 600px;"` to `<div class="modal-dialog">` to see if that will work.