# Change bootstrap 3 modal width maintaining responsiveness

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I just read on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169432/how-can-i-change-the-default-width-of-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-box) that you can change bootstrap modal width with this:

```
.modal .modal-dialog { width: 800px; }
```

But when I do this, I loose the default responsiveness of the modal.

How can I change the width but keep the responsiveness on mobile?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just use `max-width`. It will become responsive-

```
.modal .modal-dialog { width: 800px; max-width:100%; }
```

Or, You can do it via media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .modal .modal-dialog {
        position:relative;
        width:auto;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but it's loosing the right margin.

Comment: Did you add any margin?

Comment: Not really. Just set width and max-width.

Comment: I just figured out that max-width:95%; keeps like a right margin, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

Comment: Edited the answer. If you use media queries. It'll work perfectly.