# changing the default width of bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change the default width of the dialog but it's not working.I have tried solutions mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169432/how-can-i-change-the-default-width-of-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-box/16090509#16090509) post. Here is my HTML code below:

```
<style>

#myDialog .modal-dialog{

width:80%;

}


</style>


<div id="myDialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                <div class="modal-title" id="Dialog_title">Text Document</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="my_doc_content"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="rg.closeDialog('myDialog');">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And adding the the `modal-lg` class doesn't work or it's too wide for you?

Comment: Adding `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">` didn't result in any change for me. The size was same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a JSFiddle that may help you: [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n63gm6f/1/)

When CSS style is added on the class `.modal` instead of `.modal-dialog`, you can then simply change the width of the modal as you want by the following code:

```
.modal{
    width: 80%; /* respsonsive width */
    margin-left:-40%; /* width/2) */ 
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myDialog").modal("show");
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.modal{
  width: 80%; /* respsonsive width */
  margin-left:-40%; /* width/2) */ 
}
```

```html
<div id="myDialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        <div class="modal-title" id="Dialog_title">Text Document</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="my_doc_content"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="rg.closeDialog('myDialog');">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2n63gm6f/1/ this is not responsive and this answer is not working for me. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 9):

**Override** the `.modal-dialog` width

```
.modal-dialog{
   width: 80%;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Place this piece of code in after the `bootstrap.min.css` to override its default width.

Here is **[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n63gm6f/1/)**

Comment: working fine but it is not responsive

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest to work with *non-built* files, working with sources you can take benefits from *variables*, *mixins* and, when needed, *add/modify* some default behaviour not explicitly exposed...

so, going to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.3/scss/_modal.scss you can see where sizes are defined and add/edit them as you need...

```
// example
@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  .modal-extralg { max-width: $modal-lg * 2; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use id:

```
#myDialog {
    width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using bootstrap 4+, there are default optional sizes,
[check this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#optional-sizes)

You can make modal-md, modal-lg in different grid sizes

Example:

```
div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered" role="document"
```