# MVC5. How to hold dialog form size when validation error has appeared

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Issue : When user edit item from the list(in dialog form) and entered more than allowed symbols the dialog form changed it's size.(After validation error occurred (See screen attached)

[How it opens in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05CDJ.png)

[After Validation error occurred, form size changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e39jZ.png)

View:

```html
@model Maintenance.Models.AppVersion


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit App Version</h4>
        </div>

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AppVersion1)

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group margin-bottom">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppVersionDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppVersionDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppVersionDescription, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error-tooltip" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save changes" id="approve-btn" />
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

  }
```

Layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Moving Pro Services</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Moving Pro Services", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Companies", "Index", "Companies")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("App Versions", "Index", "AppVersions")</li>
                                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                                {
                                    if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                                    {
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create User", "Register", "Account")</li>
                                    }
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr/>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Moving Pro Services</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id='myModalContent'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Script(Show dialog):

```js
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).on("click", ".modal-link", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal
                (
                {
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show'
                );

            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click", "a[data-modal]", function (e)
    {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function ()
        {
            $('#myModal').modal
            (
                {
                  keyboard: true
                }, 'show'
            );

            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(window.document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('[autofocus]', this).focus();
        }.bind(this), 100);
    });
});


function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {

        var isValid = true; // assume all OK
        $('form').validate(); // perform validation on the form
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function (index, item) { // could change selector to suit e.g $('input, textarea').each(..            
            if (!$(this).valid()) {
                isValid = false; // signal errors
                return false; // break out of loop   
            }
        });
        if (!isValid) {
            return false; // exit
        }
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {

                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    //location.reload();
                    alert(result.message);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Index:

```html
@model Maintenance.Models.AppVersionsSearchModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h3>App Versions</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "AppVersions", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AppVersion1, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "App Version" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                <input name="SearchButton" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-control grid-control-app-version">
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true,
            rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
            canSort: true,
            ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid"
            );
            grid.Bind(Model.AppVersions, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
            @grid.GetHtml(
                fillEmptyRows: false,
                tableStyle: "webgrid-table webgrid-table-app-version",
                headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column(header: "Action", canSort: false, style: "action",
                        format: @<text>
                        @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/AppVersions/Details/" + item.AppVersion1 + "' id='" + item.AppVersion1 + "' title='Detail'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'> </span> </a>")
                        @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/AppVersions/Edit/" + item.AppVersion1 + "' id='" + item.AppVersion1 + "' title='Edit'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> </a>")
                        @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/AppVersions/Delete/" + item.AppVersion1 + "' id='" + item.AppVersion1 + "' title='Delete'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span> </a>")
                        </text>
                        ),
                    grid.Column(columnName: "AppVersion1", header: Sorter("AppVersion1", "App Version", grid), style: "AppVersion-AppVersion1"),
                    grid.Column(columnName: "AppVersionDescription", header: Sorter("AppVersionDescription", "App Version Description", grid), style: "AppVersion-AppVersionDescription"),
                    grid.Column(columnName: "CreateDate", header: Sorter("CreateDate", "Creation Date", grid), style: "AppVersion-CreateDate")
                    )
                )
            ;
        }
    </div>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
           @Html.ActionLink("Create New App Version", "Create", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-primary",  data_target = "#myModal", data_toggle = "myModal" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@functions {
    public static string Sorter(string columnName, string columnHeader, WebGrid grid)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", columnHeader, grid.SortColumn == columnName ?
            grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "▲" :
                "▼" : string.Empty);
    }
}

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/ProcessingModalDialog.js")
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('th a, tfoot a').click(function () {
            $('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169432/how-can-i-change-the-default-width-of-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-box <-- Can you restrict the size of the modal set a max-width for via CSS. This should make the validation wrap and keep the modal the same size in theory.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Size of dialog is kept. But the dialog move to the right side of the screen. Why is position of the dialog changed?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the lines in your modal.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppVersionDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppVersionDescription, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error-tooltip" })
</div>
```

When you run your code right click on the modal entry box and check the html generated. You will see that the EditorFor template and ValidationMessageFor become one line as the Validation is added into the  as a .

You have a choice, you can style the Modal width and set a max-width class to your EditorFor entry to the  wraps to the line underneath.

Or

You can put the ValidationMessageFor outside the Current  block and try that.